# Initializing a subclass with an existing superclass instance in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, inheritance, superclass

I am writing my own version of the socket class in python.
I was wondering if there is a way to **not** initialize the subclass using it's `__init__` method, but rather initialize it using an **existing instance of the socket class**.

Basically, what I am trying to do, is inherit from the socket class, and overwrite the `accept()` method to return an object of my own class instead of the socket class.

To get around this problem I want to implement the possibility to set a base socket in my `__init__` method in my custom socket class, which takes the instance of a socket as argument and **creates a new instance of my custom socket class** using **an existing instance of the socket class**, or do the same using a `fromSocket()` classmethod.

My question now is how do I set an existing instance of the socket class as superclass for my own socket **without using an attribute to contain the socket object**? (Is that even possible in python?)

All the other related questions I found were more on how to change a superclass at runtime. I may have overlooked the answer somewhere, but I couldn't find it.

My code looks something like this:

```
import socket
class MySocket(socket.socket):
    def __init__(self, sock:socket.socket=None):
        if sock != None:
            # initialize using existing instance contained in sock
            # How? (My question)
        else:
            super().__init__() # Default conf is enough for now
    def accept(self):
        s, addr = super().accept()
        return MySocket(sock=s) # <= This is what I want to do
```

and I want to call it like this:

```
s = MySocket()
# Call bind and listen, left out because it doesn't matter here
client, addr = s.accept() 
# Client is an instance of socket.socket, but it should be MySocket
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the source code for [`socket.accept()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/socket.py#L205-L219).

Honestly, this looks like a mistake on the `socket` class, they've hardcoded it to create a new instance of `socket`:

```
sock = socket(self.family, self.type, self.proto, fileno=fd)
```

When it probably should fetch the type of `self` instead:

```
sock = type(self)(self.family, self.type, self.proto, fileno=fd)
```

This seems to be done in multiple methods, it looks like your best chance is to copy all the attributes manually from the returned socket to your custom instance. The [`dup()` method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/socket.py#L194-L203) is hopefully correct, so we can create a classmethod that repeats its functionality:

```
import socket

class MySocket(socket.socket):
    @classmethod
    def from_socket(cls, sock):
        fd = socket.dup(sock.fileno())
        my_sock = cls(sock.family, sock.type, sock.proto, fileno=fd)
        my_sock.settimeout(sock.gettimeout())
        return my_sock
```

Comment: So you mean basically just re-write every method that returns a socket object?
And there is no way to inherit from an active instance?

Comment: Darn it, I've never used `socket` in my life, didn't realise there are so many methods that return a `socket` object. Well, you could try creating some sort of wrapper class, maybe it could use use `__getattr__` to call `getattr(self._socket, ...)`, then check the return value and if it's a `socket` object, you could manually convert it to `MySocket` by copying all the attributes etc... May I ask, what is it that you're *really* trying to do? What do you need a custom `MySocket` class for?

Comment: I want to change some methods, like the send method, to first send the length of a message as a fixed amount of bytes, so the second (longer) message can have a variable length. And all that wrapped in a single method. I also want to do a Diffie Hellman Key Exchange wrapped into a method.

Basically, once the socket `accept()`s a new client, it does a key exchange and can use a symmetrical AES key from that point on. I would have the AES key as an attribute of the socket (don't know how secure that is) so I need a custom class for that.

Comment: Alright. This is not the answer I was looking for, but it solves my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @J.Horr Yeah just to clarify an answer to your original question: no, it's not possible to initialize an instance from another instance directly, unless there is a built-in support for it in the class (such as our `from_socket()` classmethod). This all boils down to a mistake in the `socket.socket` class though, it should just use `type(self)` to instantiate new objects, instead of `socket` being hardcoded in there.

Answer (score 1):

So you want something like the equivalent of a *copy constructor*.

Although there are some things that indicate an *XY Problem*, there's a simple alternative (If I got things right).

According to [[Python 3.Docs]: socket.**socket**(*family=AF_INET, type=SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, fileno=None)*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket):

> If *fileno* is specified, the values for *family*, *type*, and *proto* are auto-detected from the specified file descriptor.

This seems to do exactly what you need.

**Note**: bear in mind that ***accept* returns a tuple**, while your override doesn't, so your class *API* is not compatible with its ancestor's.

Here's a piece of code that should do what you want:

```py
class CustomSocket(socket.socket):
    def accept(self):
        conn, addr = super().accept()
        custom_conn = CustomSocket(conn.family, conn.type, conn.proto, conn.fileno())
        return custom_conn, addr
```

Comment: This would require the CustomSocket to have the same constructor as the socket.socket class right?

Comment: Yes. I didn't change anything in the *ctor* since the inherited one seems to handle what you want. Look at the way I instantiated the socket in *accept*.