# Initialize a superclass with an existing object (copy constructor)

Tags: python, inheritance, constructor, super

Preface: From my understanding the [existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59670708/init-super-with-existing-instance) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56324214/initializing-a-subclass-with-an-existing-superclass-instance-in-python3) to this question assume control over the source or work around the problem.

Given a `Super` class, and `MyClass` which derives from it: How can an existing instance of a `Super` class be used as a base? The goal is to *not* call `super().__init__()` with fields from `existing_super`, but use the existing object. Similar to how in C++ a copy constructor would be used. Only `MyClass` can be adapted, `Super` has to remain unchanged.

```py
class Super:
    def __init__(self, constructed, by, the, super_factory):
        """ no `existing_super` accepted """
        pass


class MyClass(Super):
    def __init__(self, existing_super):
        """ ????? """
        pass


s = super_factory()

mine = MyClass(s)
```

If this is not possible, would monkey patching `Super` help? What if `Super` uses/doesn't use `slots`?

Comment: You'll have to know the details of how `existing_super` was created and reproduce them. Unlike C++, inheritance only involves defining how attribute lookup occurs at runtime; it does not affect the actual construction of an object. (This is why, for example, you need to explicitly call `super().__init__` if you want the superclass initialization to occur.)

Comment: It would be good if you could include a couple of example fields from Super to give an impression of what work MyClass has to do.

Comment: And as such, `Super` would be the correct place to define, say, a class method that takes an existing instance of `Super` and returns a new instance with the same details.

Comment: @chepner Indeed, "know the details of `Super` construction" is the crux of the problem. This is hidden by `super_factory()`, it creates `Super(..)` with a lot of arguments and this logic (subject to change) should not be duplicated in `MyClass`.

Comment: So a (monkey patched?) class method inside `Super(..)`, which iterates over the `__slots__` to create a quasi copy constructor?

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach it is to convert your instance of the super class into an instance of the subclass using the `__class__` attribute.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.A_attribute = 'from_A'


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        #Create an instance of B from scratch
        self.B_attribute = 'from_B'
        super().__init__()

    def init_A(self):
        #Initializes an instance of B from what is already an instance of A
        self.B_attribute = 'from_B'

myA = A()
myA.__class__ = B
myA.init_A()
```